# Employer Liability / walking between buildings?

Tags: work-time, law

Recently a U.S. employer told us not to skate(board) between buildings because they were liable for us.  Is this true?

The buildings were leased by the employer from a single landlord.  The space between the two buildings (e.g. parking lot, sidewalk, ...) is owned by the landlord.

When you walk on the landlord's property between two workplaces is the employer really liable?  I thought this kind of liability was all state-by-state and covered by Worker's Compensation, not the liability of the employer...

Comment: Why do you Americans love lawyers so much?

Comment: I don't love them...  I just need to deal with them...

Comment: I guess i am lucky. The first thing we think about when had an accident in the UK is not a lawyer.  Thar is way down the list

Comment: IANAL - but in some jurisdictions, where there may be some kind of state backed agency which provides worker's compensation, that agency may then sue your company to recover your compensation (with a punitive fine on top) if your company is deemed to be at fault. Because you have to walk across a space to get from one building to another to conduct normal business, your company is just as liable as if you were walking down the hall of the building you are in.

Comment: Also - you do realise how ridiculous grown adults look when trying to look cool by skateboarding across flat car parks - maybe your company is trying to reduce the embarassment factor

Comment: @HorusKol : Ridiculous but efficient. Kick scooters too, are efficient, they can divide by more than two your walking time without needing a shower at the arrival. For big business parks served by public transit only on one end, it can be a very wise investment. Even if ridiculous.

Comment: LIkely a lawyer did advise them to do that,lawyers tend to be conservative about these things for good reasons.  However, whether it is actually illegal or not is a moot point. Why would you care? You have been told not to do it and if you do it, you are very liable to lose you job (given the lack of worker protections in the US) because they don't want to take on that risk. So why care if it is actually a legal issue for your employer? You are going to need to do it anyway.

Comment: You also would not be aware of this as it would not necessarily be public knowledge, but there is a strong possibility someone did get hurt and it cost the company leading to the new policy. Companies often make new policies after they have been burned due to the lack of policy.

Comment: They didn't say if that was liability in case you hurt yourself, or liability in case you hurt someone else on your skateboard.

Answer (score 5):

Injuries on their property are likely to be charged against their insurance, yes.  At the very least it will cost them a lot in lawyer's time, and juries have a bad habit of trying to make everything the company's fault.

In any case it's their property, and them writing the paycheck. If you want to come into the former to earn the latter this is a particularly unwise argument to get into. Pick your battles,

Comment: Sounds like a pretty general, conventional wisdom answer, yet it flies in the face of the Workers Compensation descriptions on the web ( http://www.dir.ca.gov/dwc/InjuredWorker.htm and http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/workplace-injury-lawsuit-sue-30334.html).  I'll give up skating back and forth between offices.  They can *pay me to walk*, but I still won't be able to sue them if I get run over in the parking long.

Comment: Legal advice is off topic,  consult someone trained to advise,  not random international strangers on the Internet,  voting to close.

Comment: I'm not looking for an expert witness or a lawyer.  That advice is typically far too conservative.  That advice typically puts you in a situation to do the safest possible thing.  The safest thing is typically not to engage in any business relationship at all.  I'm looking or real advice from real people (HR, Executives, Insurance Agents, or employees with experience) as opposed to a lawyer telling me not to do anything or a lawyer telling me to sue everybody.

Comment: From you comments, it looks like that you are looking for someone that tells you that you can do whatever you want. I am having a nice day, so here is my answer: You can do whatever pleases you most. If you get in trouble from that, do not forget to tell the other party that I told you that you could do whatever you wanted; that should solve any issue.

Comment: I found out more insight from my client.  They said that Worker's Comprehensive insurance is provided by a private carrier.  That means they care a lot about what you do because it costs them money.  If it were purely a government run program, they wouldn't have much to say about what you do walking between buildings.